# Removing the delay on text animation - HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```css
/*Vertical Flip*/

.verticalFlip {
  display: inline;
}

.verticalFlip span {
  animation: vertical 5s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: vertical 5s linear infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: vertical 5s linear infinite 0s;
  color: #ea1534;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.verticalFlip span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}


/*Vertical Flip Animation*/

@-moz-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


/* text */

#hero h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 56px;
  color: transparent;
  background: url("https://lovelytab.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Tumblr-Aesthetic-Wallpapers-Free.jpg") repeat;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<section id="hero">
  <h1 style="margin-bottom: 16px">Sample
    <div class="verticalFlip"><span>Change</span><span>Text</span></div>
  </h1>
</section>
```

This is working fine, however, how can I remove the delay? There is a long pause after the text alternating gets completed. I would like it to be instant where it keeps on alternating the text in a smooth manner. The only thing I would like to remove is the long pause, that is it. I am not sure which css property is causing that issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: So that appears intentional with your duration time and the 30% - 100% opacity keyframes completing. Are you just trying to have a continuous flip in/out between them?

Comment: Yes @ChrisW. I want a continuous flip in/out between them

Comment: The animation is meant to use 4 text items but you don't have a `:nth-child(3)` or `:nth-child(4)` in the HTML. Reduce the `12.5s` to a duration suitable for having only two items such as, for example, `5s`.

Comment: I made the required changes but there is still a delay

Comment: Have you analysed what the keyframes are? They were set up in  your original question to deal with more words. You have removed the middle part of that but that isn't enough, you need to calculate how long (in % terms) each of the two remaining words needs to have to rotate/change opacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to play around with the ***animation duration*** and also adjust the **key frames *percentages*** -> the ***tween*** in when you are flipping the text using your ***transform/opacity*** rules.

I have slightly adjusted each, but this comes down to a taste in how you want it to ***look and feel***. Spreading the flipping animation over more of a percent (your tween) will lessen the amount of time you have in a pause between animations.

```css
/*Vertical Flip*/

.verticalFlip {
  display: inline;
}

.verticalFlip span {
  animation: vertical 3.4s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: vertical 3.4s linear infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: vertical 3.4s linear infinite 0s;
  color: #ea1534;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.verticalFlip span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
}


/*Vertical Flip Animation*/

@-moz-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  15% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  35% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  15% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  35% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  95% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  15% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  35% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  55% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  95% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


/* text */

#hero h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 56px;
  color: transparent;
  background: url("https://lovelytab.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Tumblr-Aesthetic-Wallpapers-Free.jpg") repeat;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<section id="hero">
  <h1 style="margin-bottom: 16px">Sample
    <div class="verticalFlip"><span>Change</span><span>Text</span></div>
  </h1>
</section>
```